# UnicodeDecodeError Sentiment140 Kaggle

Tags: database, python-3.x, encoding, import, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to read the Sentiment140.csv available on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/kazanova/sentiment140

My code is this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

cols = ['sentiment','id','date','query_string','user','text']
BASE_DIR = ''
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Sentiment140.csv'),header=None, names=cols)
```

And it gives me this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position
>   80-81: invalid continuation byte

The things I would like to understand are:

1) How do I solve this issue?

2) Where can I see which type of encoding should I use instead of "utf-8", based on the error?

3) Using other encoding methods will cause me other issues later on?

Thanks in advance

P.s. I am using python3 on a mac

Comment: If anyone has the same problem, I opened the file in a text editor (for instance Notepad++ or SublimeText) and saved the file again by selecting UTF-8 with BOM. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Akalyn well this approach doesn't work for me. In fact if I check with `with open("myfile.csv") as f: print(f)`, it still says `mode='r' encoding='cp936'`, and same error occurs when I try to read in.

Answer (score 1):

This works:
https://investigate.ai/investigating-sentiment-analysis/cleaning-the-sentiment140-data/

Turns out `encoding="latin-1"` and you have to specify column names, otherwise it will use the first row as column names. This is how lousy real-world dataset can be haha